# How do I get all django response form data in a test

Tags: django, forms, testing, response

I want to write a generic django test that tests views by simply requesting an arbitrary edit URL, taking all the data in the forms in the response context and then POST-ing that to the same URL without changes.

Does django provide a simple way to get all this form data from a response object, i.e. in a way for any response object? One problem is not knowing where the forms are in the response.context.

EDIT: to clarify :- If the response html only has one form, then retrieve all the data in that form that would be sent if the user simply hit the submit button, and POST that to the same URL.

Having slept on it, using BeautifulSoup to parse the response content, look for a form and extract the data there would be an easy solution, and closer to what the user is actually going to see than looking through the response.context (e.g. a template doesn't have to render a form, so the user might not actually see it). The only downside is it will be a bit slow, I have hundreds of such tests to run.

Any better ideas?

Comment: I'm not following your question at all. Any variable set in a view will be available in the response context: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#testing-responses

Comment: When you say "get all the POST-able" data...what are you talking about?

Comment: Clarified in my edit:- assuming a single form in the HTML, all the data that would be submitted by that form if the user simply submitted it without changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-webtest](https://github.com/kmike/django-webtest) but internally it is the same as your solution with BeautifulSoup.